# Can a US J1 visa holder apply for a Macedonia Tourist Visa?

Tags: visas, filipino-citizens, macedonia

I'm from the Philippines and I'm a J1 visa holder currently doing my internship here at the US. I was just wondering if I can apply for a tourist visa for Macedonia while I'm still here. If so, What are the requirements? How long does it take and is there a big chance of being rejected?

Answer (score 1):

Getting a Macedonian visa as a Filipino is a pain in the neck, as you must obtain clearance from the Macedonian police (obtained through the embassy).

If I were you, I would apply at least 2 months before travel.

From what I can find, you have to apply in person, submitting your passport, a photograph, proof of funds (e.g. your last bank statement), flight and hotel confirmations and proof of travel insurance.

That said, since the embassy doesn't have a website of its own, you need to E-Mail them at washington@mfa.gov.mk, briefly present yourself and let them know you wish to apply for a tourist visa.